# Data available in controller but not parsing in the html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new at AngularJS and i've been trying to make a simple application that gets data from a API and i need to show that data on the client browser.

I have managed to get the data and i can access it on the controller, by using `console.log` , but when i try show that data on the HTML via a angular expression, it shows nothing. The data is written on the console log but not on the HTML, below there are the codes for my HTML and my Controller:

HTML:

```
<body class="list-group" ng-controller="StoreController as store">
    <header>
      <h1 class="text-center">Learning Angular</h1>
      <h2 class="text-center">– This is pretty fun –</h2>
    </header>       
    <div class="sizeLimitter">
        {{store.posts[0].title}}
    </div>
</body>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('StoreController', ['$sce', '$scope', '$http', function( $sce, $scope, $http ) {
    this.products = gems; // Using on other parts and working as intended.

    // urlPosts contains the original link, which i cannot share.
    var trustedUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(urlPosts); 

    this.posts = $http.jsonp(trustedUrl, {jsonpCallbackParam: 'callback'})
    .then(function(postsRecieved) {
        this.posts = postsRecieved;
        console.log(postsRecieved.data[0].title);
        console.log(posts.data[0].title);
});

}]);
```

Example of JSON:

```
    [
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
  }]
```

The title is printed twice on the console, so it works for both `postsRecieved.data[0].title` and `posts.data[0].title`. What am i doing wrong here and how do i fix it, so that the data can be shown on the html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few mistakes in a controller:

1. `this.posts` in query resolve function is not not a scope's `posts`
   property because  `this` in controller and `this` in resolve
   function are different. So, you should make scope available in
   resolve function by creating a `scope` variable in controller
2. your view expects data array in `scope.posts`, not http result object.
   So, you should put `postsRecieved.data` in `posts` property.

Here is a full Controller code:

```
app.controller('StoreController', ['$sce', '$scope', '$http', function( $sce, $scope, $http ) {
    this.products = gems; // Using on other parts and working as intended.
    //make scope available in .then(function)
    var scope = this;
    //initialize an empty array of posts. this is not nesessary, but good for code understanding
    scope.posts = [];

    // urlPosts contains the original link, which i cannot share.
    var trustedUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(urlPosts); 

    this.posts = $http.jsonp(trustedUrl, {jsonpCallbackParam: 'callback'})
    .then(function(postsRecieved) {
        //put data into сorresponding scope's property
        scope.posts = postsRecieved.data;
        console.log(postsRecieved.data[0].title);
        console.log(scope.posts.data[0].title);
    });

}]);
```

Comment: Very clear and informative answer! Not only it worked but i actually understood what i did wrong and how to fix it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It should be like to this.Because you using `then` function

```
 var self = this;
$http.jsonp(trustedUrl, {jsonpCallbackParam: 'callback'})
.then(function(postsRecieved) {
    self.posts = postsRecieved.data;
});
```

Comment: I have tried doing what you proposed and it still does not work. The results are the same as before.

Comment: Try use `var self = this;` instead of `this`. so instead of `this.posts` should be `self.posts`

Comment: my answer is same and before that too.

Answer (score 0):

*this* in #hhtp request is windows object and is not same as *this* in controller.
so you have to save *this* before you use $http request like that:

```
var vm = this;
```

and in success of request is:

```
vm.posts = postsRecieved.data;
```

hier can you see a example for $http request:
https://codepen.io/miladfm/pen/rwNemb